# Change URL when I change dropdown item selected in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to change URL in ASP.Net when drop down item is selected. For example "www.website.com", I want to display State in URL like "www.website.com/Maharastra".
If I select District now, I want to display my URL as "www.website.com/Maharastra/Mumbai".

By Default when page loads initially, I am displaying list of all states in listview and implemented URL rewriting concept which is working fine. I want to implement it in same way for dropdown list. How to do it

In Global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("StateRoute", "{StateName}", "~/Default.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary { { "StateName", String.Empty } });
        routes.MapPageRoute("DistrictRoute", "{StateName}/{DistrictName}", "~/State.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary { { "StateName", String.Empty }, { "DistrictName", String.Empty } });
}
```

In Default.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (this.Page.RouteData.Values["StateName"] != null)
  {
      dlstState.SelectedIndex = -1;
      dlstState.Items.FindByText(this.Page.RouteData.Values["StateName"].ToString()).Selected = true;
      dlstState_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
  }
  if (this.Page.RouteData.Values["DistrictName"] != null)
  {
      dlstDistrict.SelectedIndex = -1;
      dlstDistrict.Items.FindByText(this.Page.RouteData.Values["DistrictName"].ToString()).Selected = true;
      dlstDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: URLs are readonly. You can't them them like this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in javascript. Take a look at this function:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

Executing this line of code will change the URL to `my-domain.com/new-url` (3rd option). The `Title` string (2nd option) is intended to describe the new state, and will not change the title of the document as one might otherwise expect ([for more detail](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/))

So, in your case, just get the value in the dropdownlist and use the `.pushState` function like this:

```
windows.history.pushState({}, null, <your_new_URL_here>);
```

Read more about manipulating browser history [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) (it contains information about `pushState`).

Comment: I tried it in Javascript. But ASP.Net is overwriting URL. Could you please provide solution in ASP.Net

Comment: I don't know why ASP.NET is overwriting your URL. Please take a look at this [post](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Change-Browser-URL-without-reloading-refreshing-page-using-HTML5-in-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx)